# Could not determine wrapper version

Tags: react-native

I've created a react native app, by simply doing:

```
react-native init app
```

I've followed this tutorial: [Facebook Getting Started (I use Linux)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

and I have done exactly what it says.

However, when I try to run the app (`react-native run-android`), I got the following message:

> Starting JS server...
>   Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not determine wrapper version.
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.wrapperVersion(GradleWrapperMain.java:111)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No build receipt resource found.
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.wrapperVersion(GradleWrapperMain.java:97)
>       ... 1 more
>   Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
>   Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
>   set up your Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
>   ```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have Android Studio installed and is your ANDROID_HOME setup? Is the emulator running?

Comment: Yes... but I already solved the problem. But thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to this link
https://github.com/MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle/issues/227
it's because you have some special character in your project path (like "!")

Comment: Oh my... *facepalm* my project path had a "!". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in a Flutter project as I was organizing some of my projects. In my case also found that my source path contained special characters when I change the folders, after removing it works perfectly fine. This will usually happen to project that contains java code and I think this is because java is compiled based on the path you provide, so the compiler does not understand the special characters we used