# Adding external library (.jar) in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add the YoutubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar to my Android Studio Project but nothing happens when i paste it into the app/libs folder. I have already tried the steps suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35369267/8256116) but i'm stuck.

This is what i have done so far to include the library:

[copied .jar to libs folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMAjy.png)

[added it under [File] > [Project Structure] > [Dependencies]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPArL.png)

[added it to the build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhF3d.png)

In another project i've tried it before and it worked, so i was able to compare but everything seems right except for no additional files being generated in the libs folder like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLdof.png).

Comment: `but it does not work` what doesn't work? `but i'm stuck` what are you stuck with?

Comment: basically if i paste the .jar file in my libs folder, nothing happens, so i cannot call `import` as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMAjy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the gradlew.bat file, which gave me the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not determine wrapper version.at
org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.wrapperVersion(GradleWrapperMain.java:111)at 
org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)Caused by: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: No build receipt resource found.at 
org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.wrapperVersion(GradleWrapperMain.java:97)... 1 more
```

which brought me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41571311/8256116) answer and indeed i had used an `!` in my project name. Removing it somehow solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the .jar library to 'libs' folder should work. make sure you have synced project with gradle files.. in File>Sync Project With Gradle Files